# Is there a way to add an error message to show up on webpage using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add error message handling in Javascript but am having trouble. If a user inputs a state that is not two characters in length, I am trying to have it output an error message. I also am including my renderBarChart function too if that helps.

js

```
stateSubmitButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    state = stateUserInput.value.toUpperCase();
    let stateFeedbackElem = document.querySelector("#stateFeedback");
    if (state.length == 2) {
        stateUserInput.setCustomValidity("");
        stateFeedbackElem.textContent = "";
        renderBarChart(state);
        state = "";
    } else {
        stateUserInput.setCustomValidity("Please enter a two letter abbreviated state.");
        stateFeedbackElem.textContent = "Please enter a two letter abbreviated state.";
        state = "";
    }
})
```

html

```
 <form class="form" novalidate>
    <label for="state-input">State:</label> 
    <input name="state" type="text" id="state-input" placeholder="(i.e. WA)">
    <button type="submit" id="state-submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg ml-2">Submit</button>
    <div id="stateFeedback" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: What kind of trouble or problem?

Comment: The error message never displays unfortunately!

Comment: `renderBarChart is not defined`

Comment: I actually do have it defined! I just included it in the code, and I know it works because everything is functioning. Just not my error messages.

Comment: now - `dataSet is not defined`

Comment: I actually have that defined too! I just didn't paste the entirety of my code. Just the relevant parts.

Comment: insert more js code

Comment: what errors messages do you get?

Comment: Hmm, I'm only really looking for help to modify my error output to be displayed on the webpage, when the entered abbreviated state is incorrect. It has to do with only the submit button event listener in my js and the portion of code in my html to render my error message to be displayed.

Comment: I don't get an error message. I want to be able to display an error message for validity concerns to people interacting with my app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed a couple of problems.

You have set `novalidate` on your form, which means `.setCustomValidity()` error will not be shown as validation will not be performed.

> If the [`novalidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate) attribute is set on the [`<form>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) element, interactive
> validation of the constraints doesn't happen.
>
> -- [Constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_validation_process:%7E:text=If%20the%20novalidate%20attribute%20is%20set,validation%20of%20the%20constraints%20doesn%27t%20happen.)

If `stateUserInput` is the `#state-input` input, `.textContent` should work, and the text should be set. But it is probably not shown as the `invalid-feedback` class has CSS property `display: none;`. You need to add a `d-block` class or use `invalid-feedback` element as shown in Bootstrap examples.

And just a note, prefer to add an event listener on the form and listen for the [SubmitEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent) instead of the `click` event on the submit button.